# VB app (NOT vb.net) on 1 database only

Tags: database, vb6, ms-access-2007

I just want to ask on how can you possibly connect 2 or more visual basic application with just 1 database..1 computer will act as Server pc and the other pc will just share it's database (on Microsoft Access if applicable). It is a voting system like application where voters access to a pc and submit there votes from a designated pc...

Sorry if it is a long talk i just wanted to clarify it more..

I was working on it for almost 2 weeks as of now..and still can't find a solution to it.

Thank you very much..I hope you can share you expertise on this..

Note:

It is a visual basic 6.0 or 2010 driven app...

help is very much appreciated..

Comment: Using Access in any kind of multi-user scenario is a recipe for disaster and long, sleepless nights. Consider using SQL Server Express (http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database.aspx) instead.

Comment: You also need to make up your mind about the technology you're about to use. VB6 is old and unsupported now, so VB.NET or C# would be a better choice on Windows.

Comment: What problem are you actually having? You don't seem to say...

Comment: Oh, and "2010" (assuming you mean Visual Studio) will be VB.Net.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest route to go would be create the database and forms  in Access and then split the Access database into a back end database and front end application.  Here is a good link from microsoft on how to do it in Access 2010. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx.  This will make it easier in the future if you should decide to upgrade the database or the front end application.  Also seem to be more comfortable with vb 6, in Access you can use VBA which compares very much with VB 6